# externalContext.getSession(false) returns null

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

My current platform is NB 7 rc 1 and I have a JSF 2 app with just one "managed bean". In time, I'm using Tomcat 7.0.34.

Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
 @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class CopyController implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private String pathBancoSentencas;
      private List<Arquivo> arquivosUpload;
      private HttpSession session;
      private List<String> listaPdfs;

      public List<Arquivo> getArquivosUpload() {
        return arquivosUpload;
      }
      public void setArquivosUpload(List<Arquivo> arquivosUpload) {
        this.arquivosUpload = arquivosUpload;
      }

      public CopyController() {
        arquivosUpload = new ArrayList<Arquivo>();
      }

      @PostConstruct
      public void doInit() {
          session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);  
    pathBancoSentencas = (String)session.getAttribute("DIRETORIO_TRABALHO");
  }
```

And after processing the request, the routine calls a view like this:

```
            <p:dataTable value="#{copyController.arquivosUpload}" var="arquivo" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                         paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
              <f:facet name="header">
                Item processado
              </f:facet>
              <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{arquivo.nome}" />
              </h:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

However, the view is not displayed and this error occurs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.jus.tjmg.dspace.copy.CopyController.doInit(CopyController.java:54)
    ... 70 more
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your `doInit()` method,

```
getExternalContext().getSession(false);
```

This returns `null` if the session is currently not been created yet. But yet you're explicitly expecting a non-`null` session in the next line.

You need to pass `true` to trigger autocreate.

```
getExternalContext().getSession(true);
```

See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSession%28boolean%29) (emphasis mine):

> If the `create` parameter is `true`, create (if necessary) and return a session instance associated with the current request. If the `create` parameter is `false` return any existing session instance associated with the current request, **or return `null` if there is no such session.**

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, that whole `doInit()` method is unnecessary and can be replaced by a `@ManagedProperty`:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{DIRETORIO_TRABALHO}")
private String pathBancoSentencas;
```

Or, if you're absolutely positive that you need do to it in the `doInit()`, a nicer way is to get it from `ExternalContext#getSessionMap()` instead.

```
pathBancoSentencas = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("DIRETORIO_TRABALHO");
```

You should try to *avoid* `javax.servlet.*` imports in your JSF backing bean.

Comment: But it was created before. In the moment of the error, my managed-bean already had been created.

So the session object already existed ??

Comment: The bean is not put in scope if the (post)constructors are not finished (JSF don't want to put a broken bean in scope for the case they throw an exception). Only after the (post)constructors are successfully invoked, the bean is put in scope. Only at that moment, the session would be created if not available yet.