# Error displayed after moving from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have created a project and it worked fine with MySQL.
I need to use SQL Server instead of MySQL, the exception bellow is displayed:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred
performing resource injection on managed bean ManageUserBean
```

Knowing that I made some changes on the file `spring.xml` like the following, could you please tell me what's missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeDAOJDBCTemplate" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=springDBA"/>
        <property name="username" value="hello" />
        <property name="password" value="world" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Any Reply is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this could help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758518/an-error-occurred-when-performing-resource-injection-on-managed-bean-copycontro

Comment: Sorry Iminiki, the problem isn't related with JSF: On console, it's the first exception which displayed, but this exception is the result of another exception which is explained by this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818302/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-table-and-could-not-extract-resultset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving more details about my problem by this thread [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table' and could not extract ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818302/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-table-and-could-not-extract-resultset).
I found the solution: I have to avoid calling an entity like 'User' on SQL-Server while it's considered like a reserved keyword on this database.